# Brownian motion relation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, expected-value

How to prove that $P(B_{t_1}^{(\mu)} \in A_1, \dots, B_{t_n}^{(\mu)} \in A_n) = E[1_{B_{t_1} \in A_1, \dots, B_{t_n} \in A_n}e^{\mu B_T}]e^{\frac{-\mu^2 T}{2}}$, considering that $B_t^{(\mu)} = B_t + \mu t, t \geq 0$ is brownian motion with drift?

Comment: Are you sure you have $B_t^{\mu}$ not $B_t$ in the indicator function? Otherwise Girsanov theorem should give you the result.

Comment: @fesman you're correct. Already edited. How should I proceed?

Comment: Try first to argue that: $P(B_t^{\mu} \in A)=E(1_{B_t \in A}exp(\mu B_{t}-\mu^2t/2))$. The exponential is called Radon-Nikodym derivative.

Comment: @fesman I know that I have to prove that but I just know that $P(B_{t_1}^{(\mu)} \in A_1, \dots, B_{t_n}^{(\mu)} \in A_n) = \int_{A_1 \times \dots \times A_k} p(x_1,t_1)p(x_2-x_1,t_2-t_1) \dots p(x_n-x_{n-1},t_n-t_{n-1}) dx_1 \dots dx_n$. Is this a correct way to start? I don't study this in a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

$$P(B_{t_1}^{(\mu)} \in A_1, \dots, B_{t_n}^{(\mu)} \in A_n)=\int_{A_1 \times \cdots A_n}p^{\mu}(x_1,t_1)p(x_2-x_1,t_2-t_1)\ldots p^{\mu}(x_{t_{n}}-x_{t_{n-1}},t_n-t_{n-1})dx_1\ldots dx_n$$

Here $p^{\mu}$ is the transition density of $B^{\mu}$. Using the definition of a Radon-Nikodym derivative

$$P(B_{t_1}^{(\mu)} \in A_1, \dots, B_{t_n}^{(\mu)} \in A_n)=\int_{A_1 \times \cdots A_n}Z^{\mu}(t_1)p(x_1,t_1)Z^{\mu}(t_1,t_2)p(x_2-x_1,t_2-t_1)\ldots Z^{\mu}(t_{n-1},t_{n})p(x_{t_n}-x_{t_{n-1}},t_n-t_{n-1})dx_1\ldots dx_n$$

Here $p$ is the transition density of $B$. Using standard arguments you should find

$Z^{\mu}(t_{n-1},t_{n})=exp(\mu(B_{t{_n}}-B_{t{_{n-1}}})-\mu^2(t{_n}-t{_{n-1}}))$.

You can see the arguments cancel so that

$Z^{\mu}(t_1)Z^{\mu}(t_1,t_2)\ldots Z^{\mu}(t_{n-1},t_{n})=Z^{\mu}(t_n)=exp(\mu B_{t{_n}}-\mu^2t{_n})$.

From which the rest follows easily. Assuming $t_0=0$, $T=t_n$ otherwise $T=t_n-t_{0}$.